# How to make jQuery ui datepicker button image read-only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I make my datepicker readonly I see that the user cannot type anything into the text box. However, they can still change the value using the calendar Icon. How can I hide the calendar icon so that users cannot change the date value?

I do not want to disable the datepicker since I need the value posted to the server upon form submit.

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "../calendar/images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function () {
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your header in the question sounds different, In your question you want whole calendar to be hidden and in header you want only image to be read only? What do you want exactly?

Comment: no i want text box and img both should be readonly

Comment: What is the purpose of calendar icon then?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a way to do the stuff but you can go through the following aspects:

You can set the range allowed to some invalid range so the user can't select any date:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
      minDate: -1,  // Add this one further
      maxDate: -2,   // Add this one further
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "../calendar/images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      onClose: function () {
          $(this).focus();
      }
}).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LyRwb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just destroy the datepicker when you change the input to readonly:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker("destroy").prop("readonly", true);
```

[**Demo #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/spp4H/)

Alternately, you can hide the image trigger:

```
$(".datepicker").prop("readonly", true).next("img").hide();
```

[**Demo #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/spp4H/1/)

For button trigger you can simply disable it:

```
$(".datepicker").prop("readonly", true).next("button").prop("disabled", true);
```

[**Demo #3**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/spp4H/2/)